# Why doesn't array_push() take a pdo query object as an argument

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Just curious. When pushing an array on another:

```
array_push($array_1, $array_2);
```

I get the usual behavior, but when I push a pdo query->fetchAll which contains and returns an array, nothing happens.

```
array_push($array_1, $query->fetchAll());
```

What is interesting to me is, if I assign the query object to a variable:

```
$array_fetchAll = $query->fetchAll();
array_push($array_1, $array_fetchAll);
```

It works like expected.

Comment: `array_push($array_1, $query-fetchAll());` is not correct syntax. missing `>`  -  `array_push($array_1, $query->fetchAll());`

Comment: be sure you're doing "array_push($array_1, $query->fetchAll());" and not "array_push($array_1, $query-fetchAll());"  missing arrow.

Comment: That's just a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: This behaves as expected for me.  Which version of PHP are you running and what is your current OS/environment?

Answer (score 1):

The only way this would work is using `PHP version 5.5.X` or above where a new feature allow functions to be dereferenced directly to access individual elements.

For example `echo $stmt->fetchAll()[0];` would not work if you running PHP older than `5.5.x`

`array_push` requires an array as parameter, if you are using older PHP you must store `$query->fetchAll()` into a variable.